# Error in r.squaredGLMM()

Tags: r, lme4

I am constructing GLMMs (using glmer() of "lme4" R package) and sometimes I get an error when estimating R2 values (using r.squaredGLMM() from "MuMIn" package).

The model I am trying to fit is simmilar to this one:

```
library(lme4)
lmA <- glmer(x~y+(1|w)+(1|w/k), data = data1, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

Then, to estime R2, I use:

```
library(MuMIn)
r.squaredGLMM(lmA)
```

And I get this:

```
 The result is correct only if all data used by the model has not changed since model was fitted. Error in .rsqGLMM(fam = family(x),
 varFx = var(fxpred), varRe = varRe,  :    'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Do you have any idea why this error appears? For instance, If I use only a single random factor (in this case, `(1|w)`) this error does not appear.

Here is my dataset:

```
data1 <- 
structure(list(w = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CA", "CB"), class = "factor"), k = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CAF01-CAM01", 
"CAM01", "CBF01-CBM01", "CBM01"), class = "factor"), x = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), y = c(-0.034973549, 
0.671720643, 4.557044729, 5.347170897, 2.634240583, -0.555740207, 
4.118277809, 2.599825716, 0.95853864, 4.327804344, 0.057331718
)), .Names = c("w", "k", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for all the work to get your question in shape by adding a reproducible example. Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this error but it is now reproducible based on the information in the question, so hopefully somebody else in the community will be able to help.

Comment: It's fixed now on R-forge: update to version 1.15.8

Comment: @KamilBartoń , can you post your comment as an answer?  (Just cleaning up old `lme4` questions ...)

Comment: @BenBolker done. Once the new version is on CRAN, this question could be deleted.

Comment: could be left around in case people are using outdated versions (it does happen ...)

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug that has been [fixed](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/r.squaredGLMM.R?root=mumin&r1=327&r2=335) in version >= 1.15.8 (soon on CRAN, currently on R-Forge).